# How to identify identical columns with different names across tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design, relational-database

My database has many columns that are reused across tables, but the name of the column changes.

edit: as an example: We're in telecom and deal with the 10 digit telephone number.  It's used across 100s of tables, usually with a different column_name for each table, and the datatype and format of the column are not consistent (e.g. '123-456-7890', '1234567890', int 1234567890, 1800-123-456-7890).

For training and analysis, I want to be able to link or identify these duplicates with different names.

How can I do this?

Comment: this sounds like a manual task :(

Comment: Can you give an example of what you are doing? I assume you have a primary key or foreign key setup for each table?

Comment: How much data in total? Less than 20 GB? Less than 2 GB?

Comment: How do you mean they are "identical"?   Exact same datatype?   Exact same Data?

Comment: @KamranFarzami - Even if I do it manually, is there a way to store the information in the database?

Comment: @GabrielVa - example: I work in telecom and we use the telephone number in many different ways.  That data point (the telephone number) is reused in literally 100s of tables, and it has dozens of different column names.

Comment: @Jeutnarg Billions of rows generated daily (>>20GB)

Comment: @TabAlleman Good question.  The datatype may be different & the data itself may be formatted differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> example: I work in telecom and we use the telephone number in many
>   different ways. That data point (the telephone number) is reused in
>   literally 100s of tables, and it has dozens of different column names

Ok, no, SQL Server can't identify these columns automatically for you.

If you can come up with rules for programmatically identifying a telephone number column based on available metadata (in `sys.columns`, for instance) you can write a query that will get all such columns.

If you have to go through your columns and manually decide which ones are telephone number columns, you can start manually storing this information in a meta-table of your own design.   Something like:

```
TableName    ColumnName    StandardName
Table1       Phone         PhoneNumber
Table2       HomePhone     PhoneNumber
Table2       WorkPhone     PhoneNumber
```

Where `TableName` and `ColumnName` are the actual names, and `StandardName` is a value you manually assign that will be the same "Standard" name for all the "Identical" columns.

And then this meta-table could be used/queried for reference, training and analysis.

Answer (score 0):

If foreign keys were declared with a references constraint,  that should help you at least with the the key fields.

Sometimes, but not always, the database designer will have used User Defined Types to specify a given data format once, instead of repreating the same definition in lots of columns.  If so, then multiple tables that refer to the same UDT will all have the same form, although not necessarilty the same exact semantics.

A quick study of the system tables should show you how to query them and group by the UDT name.  That ought to bring columns but the same data together.

Comment: This is a good idea, but I don't think it will help because our database design wasn't done with much specificity.

As an example, we use the telephone number across hundreds of tables.  This can be a Varchar, an int, a concatenation with other fields...  And on top of that we almost always have a different name for the column in each table.

I've looked for ways to identify such duplications of the same semantic column, and haven't found them.

I'm leaning towards creating a reference table manually to identify these cases.

Comment: Sounds right.  In the bad old days before databases, people had to manually construct data dictionaries, in order to make sense of the confused welter of fields in files.  That seems to be coming around again, as more and more legacy databases are examined, and found to have been designed with no thought of integrated data management.

Comment: That's exactly the case at work.  We deal with many legacy systems through decades of acquisitions...